# Create plugin cakephp and use it in browser

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to create a [plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html), this is my folder layout;

[image: Folder layout]

in bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('ContactManager');
```

in routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/ct/', 
    array(
        'plugin' => 'ContactManager', 
        'controller' => 'Contacts', 
        'action' =>'index'
    )
);
```

ContactManagerAppController.php

```
<?php
class ContactManagerAppController extends AppController {}
```

ContactsController.php

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends ContactManagerAppController {
    public $uses = array('ContactManager.Contact');

    public function index() {
        //...
    }
}
```

ContactManagerAppModel.php

```
<?php
class ContactManagerAppModel extends AppModel {}
```

Contact.php

```
class Contact extends ContactManagerAppModel {}
```

How do I display index.ctp in my browser
index.ctp

```
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

Requesting `http://localhost/cakephp/ct/ContactManager/Contacts` gives a missing controller error, instead of my plugin controller index:

[image: 404 for plugin url request]

Comment: oh no
http://localhost/cakephp/ContactManager/Contacts

it doesn't work

Comment: Your screenshot is still of `http://localhost/cakephp/ContactsManager/Contacts`.  Since you created a route so that `/` points at your plugin, the url `http://localhost/cakephp` will point at that controller action _and if it doesn't_ means that something more basic is wrong like looking at the wrong app/editing the wrong files the plugin _not_ being loaded etc.

Comment: Router::connect('/ct/', array('plugin' => 'ContactManager', 'controller' => 'Contacts', 'action' =>'index'));

and my link: http://localhost/cakephp/ct/ContactManager/Contacts
it doesn't work, :(

Comment: Well, that's no surprise since that doesn't match the route in your comment, and doesn't match any other route either. That'll just cause a "missing ct controller" error. I recommend you [get on irc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/where-to-get-help.html#the-irc-channel) as it looks like you have a few misunderstandings that need clearing up.

Comment: can u teach me create 1 plugin

Comment: You already have, your problems isn't creating a plugin its something else. SO is the wrong format for that kind of help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your plugin's Contacts Controller (without setting up routes) from `/contact_manager/contacts`. So by the looks of your question the absolute URL should be:-

```
http://localhost/cakephp/contact_manager/contacts
```

If this is not working then there's something wrong with the plugin's setup. Make sure the plugin files are readable and that the filenames and classes are all correct. Your plugin structure looks good otherwise.

If the above URL works then (and only then) you can consider re-routing it. To do this you need to do something like this (preferably in `/app/Config/routes.php`):-

```
Router::connect(
    '/ct/', 
    array(
        'plugin' => 'contact_manager', 
        'controller' => 'contacts', 
        'action' =>'index'
    )
);
```

If the route does not work try checking that nothing is overridding it elsewhere in your routes file.

You should use snake case (*e.g.* 'contact_manager') not camel case (*e.g.* 'ContactManager') in your route parameters.

Comment: tks u! i know where i wrong
in folder missing folder Config (bootstrap.php and routes.php)
http://i.imgur.com/Ju8mq4D.jpg

Comment: @Scyllar01 has this fixed your problem? If so please accept the answer so that others finding this page can solve their issues too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**This is my answer  ---> thanks all**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHXQG.jpg

in Controller:

```
AppController.php
ContactsController.php
```

in Model

```
AppModel.php
Contact.php
```

in View/Contacts

```
index.ctp
```

app/Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/ct', array('plugin'=>'ContactManager', 'controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load(array('ContactManager' => array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true) ));
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct. Are you implying you've created AppController and AppModel within your plugin?